tensorflow.js loadLayersModel fetch failed
I want to use the model I trained with tensorflow, but I'm getting errors. Please help me
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
const path = require("path")

const MODEL_PATH = "tfjs_Model/model.json"
const loadModel = async () => {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(`file://${MODEL_PATH}`);
    return model;
};

module.exports = loadModel;

node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12500
      Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
            ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12500:13 {
  [cause]: Error: not implemented... yet...
      at makeNetworkError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4549:35)
      at schemeFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10008:34)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9857:26
      at mainFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9876:11)
      at fetching (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9824:7)
      at fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9694:20)
      at fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12498:10)
      at fetch (node:internal/bootstrap/web/exposed-window-or-worker:79:16)
      at PlatformNode.fetch (C:\Users\Candar\Desktop\Bitirme\ModelTests\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:8417:33)
      at HTTPRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Candar\Desktop\Bitirme\ModelTests\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-core\dist\tf-core.node.js:25938:55)
}

Node.js v21.7.3

I couldn't fix it no matter what I did.

undici doesn't fetch file://
It's related to this: https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/2751
